# Как можно сократить SQL-запрос?

Tags: sql

Такой вот страшненький он.

```
$db->query("UPDATE `list` 
               SET `checked` = 1 
             WHERE `id` = $getList1[0] 
               AND `id` = $getList1[1] 
               AND `id` = $getList1[2] 
               AND `id` = $getList1[3] 
               AND `id` = $getList1[4] 
               AND `id` = $getList1[5] 
               AND `id` = $getList1[6] 
               AND `id` = $getList1[7] 
               AND `id` = $getList1[8] 
               AND `id` = $getList1[9] 
               AND `id` = $getList1[10]");
```

Comment: У вас в массиве одинаковые элементы? Если нет, то запрос работать не будет. id не может быть равно 3 и 5 одновременно.

Comment: Наверно должно быть 'OR'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$db->query("UPDATE `list` SET `checked` = 1 WHERE `id` IN ('". implode("','", $getList1) ."')");
```

Comment: @evz если ID - некое рандомнон число, работать будет?

Comment: Если массив $getList1 будет содержать идентификаторы, которые есть в таблице list, то запрос на обновление сработает.